# Prevent API returned data from overwriting empty input onFocus

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a series of input fields when **onBlur** (focusOut) fires an API call posting the data within each input. My issue is, when I leave (onBlur) one input field and go into another, I set the new state of the input to ''.

This works great until the previous **onBlur** call returns the response which updates the total. When the response comes, it overwrites that state of the focused input with the previous value. Is this preventable?

```
  updateTotal = async ( id, inputValue) => {
    const {dispatch, programKey, calculatorKey} = this.props;
    const goals = this.getActiveGoals();
    const timePeriodKey = this.getActiveTimePeriod().key
    const getFromState = goals.filter(goal => (goal.key !== id && (goal.key in this.state.goals))).map(goal => ({metricKey: goal.key, value: this.state.goals[goal.key]}))
    const getFromGoals = goals.filter(goal => (goal.key !== id && !(goal.key in this.state.goals))).map(goal => ({metricKey: goal.key, value: goal.goalValue}));
    const filteredFromGoals = goals.filter(goal => (goal.key === id)).map(goal => ({metricKey: id, value: inputValue}));
    const combinedGoals = getFromGoals.concat(filteredFromGoals, getFromState)

    await dispatch(
      metricApiActions.createCalculatorCalculateByCalculatorKey(
        { programKey, calculatorKey, timePeriodKey, body: combinedGoals }
      )
    )
    dispatch(
      metricApiActions.createCalculatorGoalsCalculateByCalculatorKey(
        {programKey, calculatorKey, body: []}
      )
    )
    this.postGoals(programKey, calculatorKey, timePeriodKey, combinedGoals)
  }

  handleFocus = (e, key) => {
    return (
      e.target.value = ''
    )
  }

  handleChange = (key, e) => {
    const verifyPositiveNumber = Math.abs(e.target.value)
    this.setState({goals:{...this.state.goals, [key]: verifyPositiveNumber}});
  }

  render() {
    const total = this.getActiveTotal();
    const goals = this.getActiveGoals();
    return (
      <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide}>
        <ModalHeader closeButton={true} />
        <ModalBody>
            {goals.sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder < b.sortOrder ? -1 : 1).map((item, i) => (
                <GoalItemContainer key={item.key} className="col-md-24">
                  <GoalItem className="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-20 col-sm-20 col-xs-20 "><Text>{item.label}</Text></GoalItem>
                    <GoalItemInput 
                      id={item.key}
                      type="number"
                      min='0'
                      className="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-md-pull-1 col-sm-pull-1 col-xs-pull-1" 
                      name={item.key}
                      onBlur={(e) => {this.updateTotal(item.key, e.target.value)}}
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(item.key, event)}
                      onFocus={(e) => this.handleFocus(event, item.key)}
                      value={this.state.goals[item.key] !== undefined ? this.state.goals[item.key] : item.goalValue && item.goalValue === null ? '0' : item.goalValue && item.goalValue !== null ? item.goalValue : ''}
                    />
                </GoalItemContainer>
              ))
            }
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Ok. I'm mapping over my input fields and getting 4 inputs back. I set the input values and updateTotal fires. This essentially maps over current state, returned values and the input value arrays and constructs 1 array I'm passing into the post called **combinedValues**. This takes all 4 input values and sends them off for a total. When this comes back, it then injects the original input values back into the 4 inputs, although I've already clicked in another firing the function **handleFocus** which sets the e.target.value to ''.

I have setState on **handleFocus** which does correct the issue of being overrode, however, it introduces another issue of setting a new value of '' to the input if I click out versus returning the original value. I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: What did you try? You're expected to at least try and we can help if you have issues

Comment: Apologies Darren, I did but I didn't post code. I'll update. Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary to set the returned API value as the input state?  Without seeing your code I would guess that you don't need the input value to reflect the returned API value and can display that value somewhere else (since you are trying to prevent this).  If it is necessary I can give some suggestions but it would help if you post some relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DarrenSweeney and Travis James, I've updated with code and a brief explanation of whats going on. Please let me know if I need to explain a little more clearly.

Comment: can you maybe reproduce the issue on codesandbox / jsfiddle?